# Strange XML formatting with XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I was looking for some XSLT stylesheet that can handle correct indenting of my xml document and found really nice one at http://www.printk.net/~bds/indent.html.

Hope author won't blame me for such quotation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:param name="indent-increment" select="'   '"/>

  <xsl:template name="newline">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:param name="indent" select="''"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="newline"/>    
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:param name="indent" select="''"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="newline"/>    
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)='']"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="indent" select="''"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="newline"/>    
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="count(child::*) > 0">
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()">
           <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat ($indent, $indent-increment)"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:call-template name="newline"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
        </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:when>       
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does almost all I wanted except one nasty thing: it makes strange 8 spaces indent of the root element of my document (but not XML declaration). Result looks like that piece of markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <database>
           <books>
              <book id="0">
                 <ISBN value="0123456789"/>
                 <title>Some book title Language</title>
                 <hardcover value="false"/>
                 <price value="40.46"/>
                 <in_stock value="100"/>
                 <annotation>Some annotation</annotation>
              </book>
           </books>
        </database>`
```

I'm rather new to XSLT technology and spent quite a lot of time trying to understand how to fix it, but so far not succeeded. I'm using standard javax.xml.transform.Transformer class to do XSLT transormation. Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I would look carefully at the contents of the "newline" template - is there any stray whitespace in there? Note also the disable-output-escaping attribute isn't needed (whitespace is never escaped, so disabling it has no effect), but the presence of the attribute reveals that the person who wrote the code was not an expert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You don't need any special XSLT code to do indenting**.

**Use just the standard identity template, with** `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (such as this):**

```
<database>            <books>
<book id="0">
<ISBN value="0123456789"/>
<title>Some book title Language</title>
              <hardcover value="false"/>
 <price value="40.46"/>
   <in_stock value="100"/>
    <annotation>Some annotation</annotation>
   </book></books> </database>
```

**it outputs the same XML document but indented**:

```
<database>
   <books>
      <book id="0">
         <ISBN value="0123456789"/>
         <title>Some book title Language</title>
         <hardcover value="false"/>
         <price value="40.46"/>
         <in_stock value="100"/>
         <annotation>Some annotation</annotation>
      </book>
   </books>
</database>
```

Comment: I was wandering about this output option before, but even if I use it with your template it doesn't work. Actually my XML initially generated by XMLStreamWriter as one long line. When I apply template it now splitted on multiple lines but still not indented at all. Do you know what may be the reason?

Comment: You're probably using Xalan, which interprets indent="yes" in this peculiar way. Switch to Saxon, or use the Xalan-specific parameter on xsl:output which control the number of spaces to indent.

Comment: @east825: Try omitting `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and see if the result is better.

Comment: @Dimitre I understood what was the problem: there are `method="xml"` and `xslt:indent-amount="4"` attributes missing in your xsl:output tag. With them all works fine. Actually such simple trnsformation can be done without any XSLT stylesheet at all - only with `setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")` method of Tranformer class.

Comment: @east825: Glad my answer was useful. The `xslt:indent-amount` attribute is not defined in XSLT -- it must be the extension attribute Michael Kay mentioned in his comment.